# c# File.WriteAllBytes does not write half of all bytes

Tags: c#, .net, file, byte

I have this function which should save bytes into file.

```cs
public static void Build4BB()
{
    string project = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Projects\\P" + Program.CurrentProject + ".b";
    if (Program.CurrentProject == "-") 
    { 
        Misc.CastAError("choose the project first."); 
        return; 
    }
    if (!File.Exists(project)) 
    { 
        Program.Error("This project does not exist."); 
        return; 
    }
    string bytes = File.ReadAllText(project);
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[512];
    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i+=2)
    {
        byteArray[i] = Convert.ToByte(bytes.Substring(0, 4), 2);
        byteArray[i + 1] = Convert.ToByte(bytes.Substring(4, 8), 2);
        bytes = bytes.Substring(12);
        Console.Write(byteArray[i].ToString() + byteArray[i + 1] + " ");
    }

    File.WriteAllBytes(project.Substring(0, project.Length - 1) + "4bb", byteArray);
}
```

But it works only when, for example:

FF **01** ED 00...
but when second and fourth and sixth etc are zero it becomes:
FF ED...
So it like skips half of all bytes.

I tried to rewrite the function but it doesn't work.
So I need some help.

EDIT
It works like [image]

But it should like [image]

Comment: Can you give proper examples of input and output files? It's not clear why you're trying to convert 4 chars to a single byte, for instance

Comment: `string bytes = File.ReadAllText(project);` - Don't you think this is confusing _at all_?

Comment: Please check in debugger what do you have in `byteArray` when calling `WriteAllBytes`.

Comment: `bytes.Substring(4, 8)` -- why are you reading 8 characters here? The parameters are (start, length)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok I can just set array size to 513, and it will work perfectly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).